# pycharm creating module and getting data

Tags: pycharm, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a module in pycharm. The first file is "gui.py" that contains tkinter entry widgetswhich is initialize for date variable. The second file "demoModule.py is my module file. How do i extract the date data and print it out with the from gui.py. The error I am getting is" NameError: name 'date_box' is not defined"

**> gui.py**

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import demoModule

root = Tk()
root.geometry('+0+0')
root.configure(bg='black')

frame_header = Frame(root, relief='groove')
frame_header.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

label = Label(frame_header, text='Date')
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N + S)

date_now = StringVar(frame_header, value=f'{datetime.datetime.now():%d-%m-%Y}')
date_box = Entry(frame_header, width=10, textvariable=date_now, justify='center')
date_box.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, sticky=N + S)

demoModule.get_date()

root.mainloop()
```

**>demoModule.py**

```
def get_date():
    date_get = date_box.get()
    print('The date is ', date_get)
```

Answer (score 1):

ok I got it this way.....

> *gui.py*

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import demoModule

root = Tk()
root.geometry('+0+0')
root.configure(bg='black')

frame_header = Frame(root, relief='groove')
frame_header.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

label = Label(frame_header, text='Date')
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N + S)

date_now = StringVar(frame_header, value=f'{datetime.datetime.now():%d-%m-%Y}')
date_box = Entry(frame_header, width=10, textvariable=date_now, justify='center')
date_box.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, sticky=N + S)

def try_get():
    date_get = date_box.get()
    demoModule.print_date(date_get)

try_get()

root.mainloop()
```

> demoModule.py

```
def print_date(dmy):
    print('The date is ', dmy)
```